# Printing the corresponding value of an array

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to print the number of degrees of an SVM model that offers the highest degree of accuracy. I can't use `max (degree_matrix_name)` because that just gives me the highest number of degrees tested.

```
x_axis_knn_array = []
y_axis_knn_array = []
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import matplotlib as matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for b in range (6, 71):
    knnClassObj = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=b, p=2, metric='minkowski')
    knnClassObj.fit(X_train, y_train)
    knn_y_pred = knnClassObj.predict(X_test)
    y_axis_knn_array.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, knn_y_pred) * 100)
    x_axis_knn_array.append(b)
print("The highest accuracy is", max(y_axis_knn_array), "%", "at", #**[I WANT TO HAVE THE NUMBER OF DEGREES CORRESPONDING TO max_y_axis_knn_array HERE]**)
```

Comment: You can use count() for eg; a=[1,2,2,3,3,3]
print(a.count(3))   or here it should be like : maximum =  max(y_axis_knn_array)   then followed by print(y_axis_knn_array.count(maximum)).  If this your query you can also check Counter().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index the x_axis_knn_array using the location of the max accuracy in the accuracy array

```
x_axis_knn_array[y_axis_knn_array.index(max(y_axis_knn_array))]
```